# Java DecimalFormat rounding giving unexpected output

Tags: decimalformat

As per DecimalFormat documentation, the default rounding mode is HALF_EVEN.
HALF_EVEN mode definition :

**Rounding mode to round towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even neighbor.**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN

However, the below code gives the output **0.01**

```
private static final DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.print(decimalFormat.format(0.015));
```

For rounding to precision 2, the 'neighbours' here would be 1 and 2, both are equidistant from 5, so ideally it should pick the even one and round to 0.02. Am I missing something?